# Stickiness does not work with Lightning Data Table in LWC with CSS

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-datatable

I am trying to add stickiness to the first column of the the datatable(freezing the first column whilst i scroll throws the columns by scrolling horizontally) using the CSS:

```
.THIS table tr td:first-child {
        position:sticky;
        z-index: 1;
        top:0;
    }
```

But it just does not work at all. Was this a limitation with data table? can anyone please help me out?.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a security feature rather than a limitation. Its [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom) that prevents the internals of a component from being modified from outside.

But you workaround it by putting the `lightning-datatable` in a container that has a fixed height. That should do what you need.

```
<div class="slds-scrollable_y" style="height: 500px;">
    <lightning-datatable key-field="Id" data={data} columns={columns} hide-checkbox-column></lightning-datatable>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sachin, I tried it but the first column is not getting freezed!.

Comment: Can you pls add the updated code that you tried in the question itself?

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this. It works.

```
<template>
    <div style="height: 300px;">
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={data}
                columns={columns}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </div>    
</template>
```